# Java static list losing its order after some time

Tags: java, sorting, jsf, collections, linked-list

I have a static list in my `Util.java` class:

```
...
private static List<MyEntity> mainList = new LinkedList<MyEntity>();
...
static {    
    fillMainList();
}
...
public static List<MyEntity> fillMainList() {

    org.hibernate.Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try{
        setMainList(new MyEntityDAO(session).findMyEntities());
    }
    finally{
        session.close();            
    }

    return getMainList();
}
...
```

MyEntityDao.java:

```
...
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<MyEntity> findMyEntities(){
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(MyEntity.class);        
    criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("participants") );
    criteria.setMaxResults(5);      
    List<MyEntity> MyEntitys = (List<MyEntity>) criteria.list();
    List<MyEntity> ordered = new LinkedList<MyEntity>();
    ordered.addAll(MyEntitys);
    return ordered;
}
...
```

And here is `MyJSFBean.java`, where I set the list that my primeFaces dataTable will interact:

```
...
public List<MyEntity> getMainList() {
    if(mainList == null){
        mainList = Util.getMainList();
    }
    return mainList ;
}
...
```

And I call the method `fillMainList()` when I start my application (in the static block from the `Util.java` class), and after that, every 12 hours (with a scheduler) to update the list.

Every time a user enters in a JSF page, its backing bean will get this list from the `Util.java` class.

Ok so, when I start my application, I can see the list in my PrimeFaces datatable in the same order as I queried with Hibernate Criteria. But after some 10 minutes, when I enter in the page again, the list is randomly sorted... The static list lost its sort... how is that possible, I have even used LinkedList to try to maintain the sort without success...

thanks!

Comment: Why do you expect `LinkedList` to maintain a sorted order? Do you understand what `static` means? Where do you access the list and what do you do with it?

Comment: @StrongJoshua How would that help?

Comment: @user3580294 ArrayLists, seeing as they use arrays, stay in order. At least that's what I have always perceived.

Comment: @StrongJoshua Uh, no. Maintaining sorted order is not a behavior guaranteed by an `ArrayList` (or by the `List` interface in general), and `LinkedList`s don't randomly change their order. It's perfectly possible to randomize an array/`ArrayList`, and a list that randomizes itself would be next to useless (it'd be nearly impossible to work with a list where immediately consecutive calls to `list.get(0);` returned different objects.)

Comment: @user3580294 The whole point is to keep the list from randomizing itself, randomly. I doubt he's randomizing it himself, at least not on purpose. `List` (specifically `ArrayList`, since that's the one I use most often) iterators go through the list in sequential order, based on insertion. So why wouldn't utilizing an `ArrayList` be a viable option (at least to test).

Comment: @StrongJoshua Why in the world would you think that a `List` and/or `LinkedList` would randomize itself? Lists (or at least sensible implementations of lists) don't do that. Ever. Unless you wanted to be obnoxious and write a list that did exactly that. `ArrayList`s *can* be used, but seeing as it implements the exact same `List` interface as `LinkedList` does, it wouldn't make a difference. You say it self -- `List` iterators go through the list in sequential order, based on insertion. Why would a `LinkedList`'s iterator not do this?

Comment: @user3580294 you are right, there is no difference in using LinkedList and ArrayList, I got confused. Why did you ask if I understand what static means? What does it have to do with a List order? As I said, I have a JSF page that access this list. Its backing bean, will access the list using Util.getMainList(). Nobody changes my list, just the scheduler job I configured. But this job will take 12 hours to start, and the list is losing its order way before that

Comment: Well, *something*'s gotta be changing list order, and I thought it's possible you were dealing with it elsewhere and the changes were showing up in the "original" list (although I do have to admit that that's not really limited to `static`, so I guess that's a bit of a moot point).

Comment: @user3580294 I've edited my post, and put everything that matters. When I start the system the list is sorted.. some time later, its not ordered anymore in my primefaces datatable... nowhere else the list is getting changed..

Comment: Hmmm... Perhaps subclass `LinkedList` and override modification methods with versions that add in logging statements and such? If you do things right you'd be able to catch exactly when things go out of order that way.